# get parameter for JApplet not working

Tags: java, applet, japplet, getparameter

I am experiencing a little problem reading parameters from an html page to an applet.

my code (necesssary for question):

on html page:

```
<PARAM NAME = "name" VALUE = "Nicholus">
```

in applet (init):

```
String strName = getParameter("name");
```

The applet just decides to  look at me instead of getting the name value..
a few google search shows im not the only one, except I haddn't yet found the solution, so I decided to post it here in case it was already resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your work with the following working code or post your code if problem still not solved.

Here is the `ParamDemo.java` code

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class ParamDemo extends Applet{
    String strName;
    public void start()
    {
        strName=getParameter("name");
        if(strName==null)
            strName="Not Found";
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Name :"+strName,10,20);
    }
}
```

Then the Applet.html

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code="ParamDemo" width="300" height="300">
<param name='name' value="Nicholas">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Snapshot
[image]

[Ps:You need to compile your .java before using in `HTML` page and make sure that there is no problem related to leter-case of parameter-names as java is case-sensitive.Also the `.class` and `.html` files must be in same root folder).

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved, my negligence... my html had many applet codes, the params were not printed within the applet declaration of the one that needs the params. thanks for contributing.